# Intel architecture and IEEE 754 compliance (minNum and maxNum)?

Tags: assembly, floating-point, x86-64, ieee-754

I've been taking a look at the x64 software developer manual and it looks like the built-in {MIN|MAX}{S|P}{S|D} instructions do not implement the functions that are called minNum and maxNum in the IEEE 754 standard, despite Intel claiming in the same document that their CPUs are fully compliant.

Intel operations always return the *second* operand if either operand is a QNaN and neither is an SNaN, while minNum and maxNum return the *other* operand, i.e.:

```
IEE 754:
minNum(1.0, QNaN) -> 1.0
minNum(QNaN, 1.0) -> 1.0

Intel x64:
MIN(1.0, QNaN) -> QNaN
MIN(QNaN, 1.0) -> 1.0
```

Am I correct that standard-compliant minNum/maxNum functions have to be emulated with an additional check of the first operand and cannot be directly translated to the corresponding instructions?

Comment: everyone *claims* to be IEEE 754 compliant...

Comment: Searching for `IEEE` in the Intel instruction reference manual finds a couple cases where it's referred to for legacy x87 instructions: `FPREM` (remainder) rounds differently from IEEE, but `FPREM1` "computes the remainder specified in IEEE Standard 754".  So I guess back in the day, Intel added a new version of an instruction to do the rounding the IEEE-specified way.  It's possible they could introduce new versions of the SSE `min` and `max` instructions, since there is probably some room for more opcodes in the VEX (AVX) and EVEX (AVX512) coding spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are going to need extra instructions.

It is discussed in [this comment on a Julia issue thread](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/7866#issuecomment-51790572) by Arch Robinson:

> The semantics of minsd were designed back in the '90s, well before IEEE 754-2008, so that compilers could optimize the common C idiom `x<y?x:y`.

The issue goes on to suggest a sequence of AVX instructions for making it NaN-poisoning. If instead you want IEEE behaviour, then you could use

```
VMIN R, a, b           // result is b if a or b are NaN, min(a,b) otherwise
                       // so Nan is not propagated only if a is the NaN
VCMPNEQ M, b, b        // M=11…11  if b is NaN, 0 otherwise
VBLENDV Res, R, a, M   // Res = R if M=0 (b not NaN), otherwise Res=a (if b is NaN)
```

Comment: I've come here to ask this question after reading this very issue! Can't believe I've missed that.